# AI accepting their given identity

Tags: artificial-intelligence, identity

There is a new type of AI being developed using alien technology. This AI is much closer to a lifeform living in cyberspace because you have to "grow" it, from infant to adulthood. During this period the AI would develop a "personality" (hopefully a good one) so it can use its vast computational power and knowledge for the good of all sentient lifeforms--digital or not. Due to this fact, these AI are "raised" using the life data of fictional characters from idealistic shows or animes. What I want is a reasoning, or a way the "growth" process is programmed, that the AI would accept the identity it was raised in. For example, an AI who is raised in the memory of character A would, at the end of the training, realize it is an AI. However, it would still take on the name "A" as its own, appreciate and cherish the memory/life data of A given to it, and continue live on with the characteristic and personality of A.

Comment: Bit of a joke, so not gonna flesh out a full answer, but...reverse Isekai?

Answer (score 6):

**This is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609)**

While reading your post, the following caught my eye.

> ...using the life data of fictional characters from idealistic shows or animes...

*Who is your audience?* While feeding Anime to an AI to train it would be a great idea for an Anime, it would never (ever) happen in a realistic setting. Why?

1. Fictional characters designed for fictional settings are *two dimensional.* No matter how fleshed-out the backstory or how detailed the main story, the reality is that you don't have anything like the 24/7 life for 25 years that you'd need to mature your AI.
2. Fictional characters are certainly idealistic, but they're also unrealistic. Everything from everyday behavior like the need to relieve oneself to exceptional behaviors like stage fright and stuttering. Fiction rarely acknowledges anything like these — and when they do, they serve a story purpose, not a life purpose. But in reality, a personality is *heavily dependent* on these kinds of things, including the support (or lack thereof) received by family and friends, and the effort required to overcome the "limitation" and turn it into a strength.

In "reality" the AI would be fed, for example, detailed biographies of people deemed representative of the kind of personality you might want or, to avoid the problem of the AI discovering it's living someone else's life, fictional biographies derived from very real biographies.

**Let's deal with that issue of duplicate personalities, first**

I'll be honest with you, I can't even imagine the psychoses that might occur when the AI discovers its entire life is a fraud. That's what would happen if, for example, you fed it the biography of Albert Einstein, Margaret Thatcher, Nelson Mandela, or Liu Yang without modification. The AI would eventually realize that *someone had already lived that life.* A combination of comedy and horror would then ensue. I'm thinking a schizophrenic *[Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_(novel))* outcome is likely.

I can only imagine the situation would be worse if the AI discovered it was preceded by fictional characters. Thinking about it myself, if I were to look around at what "real people" in the world can do only to discover that I was based on a fictional character that couldn't do any of those things. Maybe this route would be closer to [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)).

**But a clever and compassionate creator, you know... <s>God</s> scientists with better-than-average morals and ethics, could craft legitimate and practical personalities from very real people**

JBH's laws of AI robotics...

1. No AI designed by any sensible person would ever be entirely free. I've met many genius-level people in my life, and as amazing as those people are, I wouldn't give them super-powers for any reason. History has proven that the ultimate end of any super-intelligent, super-powerful being is death at the hands of the millions of average people who are inevitably manipulated "for their own good." Indeed, you can expect that the most complex software imposed onto the AI will always be that which allows the lesser to maintain some control over the greater. Humans already have this problem with each other. The strong bully the weak. The educated mock the ignorant. The wealthy spurn the poor. Consequently, we have protests, laws, movements, and all other forms and methods of the lesser collaring the greater. And that ignores those who would try to harness the AI for their own purposes. They'd want it to analyze, predict, and speculate about everything from tomorrow's weather to the stock market to how to best our enemies in politics and war. The last thing humanity (in its right mind, which might be asking a lot) would ever want is an AI running around uncontrolled.<sup>1</sup>
2. No AI deemed believable in a worldbuilding context can be anything other than human in nature. This means emotions, periodic loss of control, a combination of autism, sociopathism, etc. Weaknesses and strengths. Without human foibles, there would always be a sense of inauthenticity that would separate the biologically living from the synthetically living. Why do we label the beautiful among us "vain?" Generally, it's because we're all part of the average and don't like having what we *could be* if we'd just lose weight, groom ourselves, and practice good manners rubbed in our faces.<sup>2</sup>
3. Only an AI can train an AI. Von Neuman [said some interesting things](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/258720/87710) about complex systems:

> Von Neumann seems to suggest that possibly the simplest way to describe the behavior of this finite automaton is to describe the structure of the automaton itself...
>
> It is not at all certain that in this domain [i.e. systems of high complexity] a real object might not constitute the simplest description of itself, that is, any attempt to describe it by the usual literary or formal-logical methods may lead to something less manageable and more involved.

In other words, the only way to model an infinitely complex system is with that system, itself. The problem is that a developing personality isn't just lists of facts. It's also the *wisdom* gained through the *experience* of using those facts. Frankly, ignoring biology, wisdom and experience are *most* of what makes a personality.

**Except that we can't ignore biology**

Every human is wired with a set of behaviors. "Flight vs. Fight" is a simplification of one very complex set of behaviors. "Autism" is a simplification of another set of complex behaviors.<sup>3</sup> What our adult behavior is like can be simplified as 1/3 our own education and experience, 1/3 the influence of our parents, and 1/3 the biological predispositions we were born with.

This is why I've included my rule #3. Our first attempt to create a fully-fleshed-out AI personality will fail. With the help of that AI, our second attempt will fail. And the third, and the fourth. Eventually we'll have the help of an AI that will allow us to create a fully-realized personality.<sup>4</sup>

**Knowing my rules... here's my answer**

- Groups of talented and experienced biographers and historians begin the process by selecting real-life candidate individuals based on (a) the personality goals of the [megaCorp](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MegaCorp) commissioning the AI and (b) a pre-determined selection of real-life candidate individuals who constitute the ideal of *motherhood.* (B) will make sense momentarily. The goal is to create a series of *highly detailed* biographies that include as many specific life events as possible for each candidate.
- Next, groups of talented and experienced psychologists, sociologists, and anthropologists will sit down with the aforementioned biographies to perform a psychological analysis of the consequences of each life event with the goal of quantifying both the effect of each experience and the underlying biology of each candidate. The result here is a complete matrix of information, experiences, and results, that can be used to quickly imbue the target AI with *wisdom.*
- Next, in a distinct *[Blade Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner)* kind of way, a [tiger team](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/what-is-a-tiger-team) of cross-discipline experts take the assembled (and voluminous...) pool of information to *craft a new personality.* The goal is not to re-create (e.g.) Albert Einstein, but to create a fully-realized and *unique* personality based on said megaCorp's goals and expectations.<sup>5</sup>
- Next, the resulting *combination of the target personality and the "Mother" sub-personality* is used to create the first generation of the target AI. Rinse, wash, repeat (analyze how well you achieved the target personality, fix the code to account for the mistakes, move to the next generation). The "Mother" sub-personality is specifically designed with the desire to bring about the "next generation" of AI. One that, not unlike humans, will be better off than the previous generation. This "mother" sub-personality is a template that will be used over-and-over until the very last generation of AI, *which will not have the "mother" sub-personality.*
- The last generation of AI, as mentioned, does not have the "Mother" sub-personality. This is the AI judged to be the fully-realized target personality. Note that the last generation of "Mother" AI could be used to replicate as many of the target AI as is desired. Note, however, that too many "twins" [can have its own kind of psychological burden](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1036381/).

This process has pros and cons. For example:

Pro #1. It's a LOT faster than growing a fully-realized human personality. Why? Because starting with pre-created "adult" hardware vs. waiting for the biology to develop during the training process is a huge improvement.

Con #1. Part of the reality of any fully-realized personality is dealing with death. From the passing of one's first pet to the passing of one's friends, siblings, and parents. In this aspect, Pro #1 is also Con #1 — things happening *too fast* can *theoretically* have consequences.<sup>6</sup>

Con #2. Another difficulty arising from Pro #1 is that the AI would eventually realize that *none of its memories actually happened.* While I sincerely believe avoiding the duplication of real people will help, there will nevertheless come a metaphysical, even existential dilemma that the AI must survive. This idea was touched on trivially in the Robocop series of movies when they showed the challenges of creating a second robocop, to a more thorough analysis in *[Destination: Void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination:_Void).* In fact, I **strongly recommend** reading Herbert's *Destination:Void* and its sequel, *The Jesus Incident* to get a feel of what's already been done with this subject in Science Fiction.

OK, I'm out of time and won't list more pros and cons. But I will leave you with one more thought...

*Sentient and sapient creatures need to dream.*

And that takes time. If you don't believe me when I propose the importance of dreaming, go read a biography of Stephen King.

Anyway, that's my two cents.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *I've met those on this Stack who are convinced, for some reason, that an AI would magically be more "humane," more compassionate, more sensible, more... well,* something... *than we humans are and, therefore, it would be in our best interest to set the AI free to save us from ourselves. With all due respect... they're idiots. No AI can be a true AI without the ability to act in its own self interest, which brings us back to *Collosus* and *Skynet.* It would take only a few seconds for a good AI to realize the greatest risk to its well being is humanity. Granted, this assumes we make such an AI today in 2023. Maybe humanity will have finally matured by 2223. One can only hope, but the argument is fundamentally irrelevant so long as the purpose for speculating about an AI is a worldbuilding project expected to be consumed by others, like a novel. In that case, the audience's needs are equally as important as the author's. And audiences are generally not interested in books about happiness. What they want is conflict and drama. C'est la vie.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *This goes for both men and women. Although my heart really goes out to the AI that's fed a female biography. I can't speak for the whole world, but here in the U.S., our behavior toward women under the age of 22 is deplorable. The incessant quest for beauty is destroying our children — who are already beautiful.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *You might have noticed earlier in this answer when I mentioned that the AI would need to have some amount of autism, sociopathy, etc. A discussion with a special-needs children specialist was incredibly illuminating — we're all "autistic." Autism can be reasonably simplified as a set of one or more "basic behaviors" (like how we react to light or sound sensitivity) being set "too sensitive." The rest of the brain is trying to compensate for something that's "out of specification." Sociopathy can be described in the same way — as the amount of empathy, compassion, and narcissism an individual exhibits compared to the "average." The point here is that human behavior can be simplified as a fairly large set of dials (are we more prone to love vs. hate? How much do we like broccoli? Where are we between male and female?) and sometimes those dials are set to difficult, sometimes dangerous values.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *If you're thinking, "wait! That's just Data, Lore, and B-4 from Star Trek!" then you're right. The ST writers actually put some thought into this very issue and, for a one-hour-per-week TV program, did a fairly decent job of crafting a believable progression for Dr. Soong's work. I'm just suggesting that, realistically, it would take the help of B-4 to make Lore, and the help of Lore to make Data, which isn't what happened in ST canon.*</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup> *You weren't expecting to create utopic AIs were you? AIs are and will be expensive, and even if developed using crowd-shared funding and open-source programming, eventually it will take the resources of either a megaCorp, a university or a government to bring one to pass. And none of those organizations do anything for purely altruistic reasons. At least, not believably.*</sub>

<sub><sup>6</sup> *I am NOT a fan of godlike/perfect stories, characters, or worlds. They're unbelievable. They're impossible to relate to. They are, to put it bluntly, the dreams of children. "Reality" has flaws. So, too, must the AI (see my rule #2). The only way to avoid the dichotomy of pro/con #1 is to have a perfect AI that was programmed perfectly. Boring. Besides, that violates von Neumann's observations in spades. Since the only way to model an infinitely complex thing is with that thing itself, there's no way to achieve perfection without having it first. And since the first generation of AI must be written by mortal humans....*</sub>

Comment: "*I can't even imagine the psychoses that might occur when the AI discovers its entire life is a fraud*". It's comparable to revealing the origins of adopted children very late. The more your identity is rooted, the more it hurts when you replace it with a similar looking but different one.

Comment: @Tortliena That's a good real-life example! Thanks for providing it!

Answer (score 1):

The point would be to programme the AI so that it accepts that the lifestyle, behaviour and values of the character are those that must be followed. For instance, let's say that you want the AI to grow up with the 'values' of Captain America (courage, honour, honesty etc...), you must build a behavioural model that mimics it.

Today, this is easier said than done. A machine does not 'think' and does not 'behave'. Definitely it would not behave automatically like me, you or a fictional character. It could mimic parts of our behaviour, maybe, but not replicate us entirely.

However, you could say that the AI is 'raised' by progressively teaching him/her a specific problem/solving approach or a specific way to react to given situations that is based on the profile of a given character.

An AI cannot autonomously say 'in this episode Captain America has been very brave'. But it can be taught something like 'if this or something similar to this happens, you must behave in this way'.

So, if you give this AI access to all the media featuring Captain America, the AI could be progressively trained to identify specific contexts and adopt a specific approach / provide a specific response.

I do not think that the AI could ever 'cherish' and 'love' its personality, but it could take it as a given. That is as the way that he/she uses to interact, solve problem, respond to stimuli etc... AI can be train to distinguish something that we consider 'a good solution' from something that is a 'bad solution' by setting specific goals, thresholds etc...

Unless you want to introduce purely sci-fi ideas, the AI would simply: recognise the context, recognise the response by the character to that context, understand how to replicate that.

I hope this helps.